# AUv3 MacOS Instrument, auval failure "Bad Max Frames - Render should fail"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, objective-c++, audiounit

This is the umpteenth time I've tried to create an AUv3 plugin, all with various amounts of success (no complete joy, ever :/ )

It works in the app, but auval fails with

```
Bad Max Frames - Render should fail
ERROR: AudioUnitRender should have returned an error for too many frames but returned noErr
```

Current OS: 10.13.5
XCode: 9.4

- created an AUv3 MacOS Instrument by creating a Cocoa Objective C app

  - added an AudioUnit app extension
  - added a Cocoa framework

etc. Details supplied if needed. *(I made notes about my steps since I've never completely succeeded previously.)* It is essentially the same as the Demo MacOS AUv3 instrument but I started the project from scratch. The only swift code is in SimplePlayEngine.swift. The rest is Objective C, Objective C++, and straight-up C++.

The only web search hit I found on this problem is [add arg to prepareInputBufferList](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/306110#306110) but there are two problems with this link:

1. Applying the change doesn't fix my problem
2. The demo AUv3 instrument builds and passes auval validation on my system with no modification.

I don't know if this is related but I find that NO breakpoint I set in the audiounit or related files (BufferedAudioBus.hpp) is ever hit. Since the audiounit functions in the app I must assume that the code is getting executed but something about the way it was built is wrong. (NSLog messages don't get printed either ... ??? (yes I know that when realtime rendering, printing to the console is a bad idea)).

I diffed between my AU source and the demo AU and the only changes are name changes. The "Build Phases" are comparable.

I know this is a pretty non-specific question, but I've run out of ideas. **Does anyone have any ideas where to look to resolve the "Bad Max Frames" auval failure?**

Comment: I added a check in the render block "if (frameCount > 4096) { return -10874; } -- This fixed the Bad Max Frames auval validation failure. Also, my AU view controller was inadvertantly both part of the app extension and the framework; that appears to be why breakpoints weren't working... Why -10874? Another AU reported that error when erroring out from "Bad Max Frames". Need the const name for that number; haven't found it yet.

Comment: Not strictly an auval comment, but it's important to note that Logic Pro X (and probably MainStage) doesn't automatically re-validate failed plugins when launching.  If auval is validating the plugin, then click "Reset and Rescan Selection" in the Plugin Manager in Logic Pro.

Comment: -10874 is kAudioUnitErr_TooManyFramesToProcess